# IOS: The PNG file contains an invalid signature: Icon.png in XCode/Organizer/Archive/Validate

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive, organizer

Five hours to attempt to publish app in the store and no result. I'm stuck with the following error: The PNG file contains an invalid signature: Icon.png during validation in Organizer/Archive. This is also the warning when I compiled my .app. I can't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that you have no .jpg files in your project, and that there are no two files that are named the same with different capitalization (icon.png vs Icon.png) Also, make sure you check your actual project file structure as well as just the files you see in Xcode (groups).

Comment: the problem was my pgn file. All names was ok. Recreate completely the PNG icon from my jpeg and now no problem in validation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

iTunes Connect has recently added more strict validation of PNGs. That said, it's possible that an icon file that previously passed validation is now failing validation because of the new rules.

In either case, try using Preview to regenerate a new icon file, like so:

1. open the png in Preview and choose File > Duplicate
2. save the duplicate in JPEG format
3. close all and reopen the JPEG version
4. duplicate the JPEG version and save the duplicate as PNG
5. replace the old png in your project with the new one, Product >
   Clean, Product > Archive, and reattempt your validation/submission

Comment: Thank you boss. You solved my problem. I recreate completely the PNG icon from my jpeg and Build/Archive/Validation now is ok. Thank you so much for your help